# In PyCharm Run/Debug, can I know on which file is the view focused on?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Using PyCharm, when creating my own Run/Debug configuration, will I have access to a variable that gives the full path of the file on which the editor is focused on when I ran the script ?

For example, my project has the following structure:

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   dtf-vision-foyer.sublime-project
│   dtf-vision-foyer.sublime-workspace
│   Jenkinsfile
│   README.md
│   saagie-properties.json
│
├───.idea
│   │   .gitignore
│   │   dtf-vision-foyer.iml
│   │   misc.xml
│   │   modules.xml
│   │   vcs.xml
│   │   workspace.xml
│   │
│   └───inspectionProfiles
│           profiles_settings.xml
```

My PyCharm is focused on the `workspace.xml` file. When running my command (<kbd>Shift + F10</kbd>), is there a variable that will be accessible to me giving me the following information:

```
C:/mypath/somewhere/myproject/.idea/workspace.xml
```

Edit: I am looking for something like [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference), from the VSCode world.

PyCharm version:

```
PyCharm 2019.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-193.6494.30, built on February 6, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.5+10-b520.38 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1898M
Cores: 8
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins: zielu.gittoolbox
```

Comment: When you create a Run/Debug configuration then the target file path will be placed in the appropriate field. There is no "dynamic file name" like `${file}` in VSCode; it will be "hardcoded" on creation (which you can still edit at any time ofc). https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-689/RunDebug-configurations-should-allow-macros  This allows executing the same Run/Debug Configuration even if you are in another file/context.

Comment: In other words: you cannot make "Debug currently opened/focused file". It's "Debug this specific file" only. If you need to use similar config for another file -- you create another config for that file (either from scratch or by using Copy/Duplicate and editing it as needed).

Comment: What a shame (17 YEARS !). That is the answer I guess. I'll accept it when you write one.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains IDEs currently do not support macros (dynamic variables) in Run/Debug Configuration fields like VSCode does.

When you create a Run/Debug configuration then the target file path will be placed in the appropriate field. There is no "dynamic file name" like `${file}` in VSCode; it will be "hardcoded" on creation (which you can still edit at any time of course). This allows executing the same Run/Debug Configuration even if you are in another file/context.

In other words: you cannot make a "Run/Debug currently opened/focused file" using an existing Run/Debug Configuration. It's "Debug this specific file" only. If you need to use a similar config for another file then you will have to create another config for that file (either from scratch or by using the "Copy Configuration" button and edit it as needed).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-689 -- this is the ticket that asks for such support. It's in the Backlog so very unlikely to be implemented any time soon.

---

**P.S.** Sure, you can still use `Run…` or `Debug…` actions and it will create a **temporary** Run/Debug Configuration for *that specific file* using your default settings (templates)  for that type of Run/Debug Configuration. Once a limit of temp configurations is reached (5 by default) the oldest used will be deleted unless it was converted into a permanent one. It’s not the same but can be used in some cases/if so desired.

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-without-any-previous-configuring.html

---

**Actually macros are supported in *some* of the fields** but definitely not in the "target" fields that point to a file.

**If the field supports macros** then it will have an appropriate icon/button in it (after clicking on it you will see a list of all macros that can be used here). Here is an example for the "Arguments / Parameters" field:

[image]
*(This one is "PHP Script" type from PhpStorm)*

[image]
*(This one is a similar type but from PyCharm; image is taken from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html)*